# What is shorter way to get the last messages among users

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am coding a message program something like WhatsApp.

I want to show the last message between user and his/her friend. But to do this, I am getting whole messages between them and using some query to find the last message. I think that I can re-write a better way. Because with that way, I get all message to memory. If I have a million messages, thats not a good way

```
    var myID = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
    var myMessages = db.MemberMessages
        .Where(m => m.MemberTo == myID || m.MemberFrom == myID)
        .Select(s => new
            {
                s.ID,
                s.Text,
                s.MemberFrom,
                s.MemberTo
            });

    List<int> messageIDs = myMessages
        .Where(s => s.MemberTo == myID).Select(s => s.MemberFrom).Distinct().ToList();

    List<int> messageIDs2 = myMessages
        .Where(s => s.MemberFrom == myID)
        .Select(s => s.MemberTo).Distinct().ToList();

    List<int> differentIDS = messageIDs2.Except(messageIDs).ToList();

    foreach (int item in differentIDS)
    {
        messageIDs.Add(item);
    }

    foreach (int userID in messageIDs)
    {
        var deger = myMessages
            .Where(m => 
                (m.MemberFrom == myID && m.MemberTo == userID) ||
                (m.MemberFrom == userID && m.MemberTo == myID))
                .OrderByDescending(m => m.ID).ThenByDescending(m => m.MemberFrom).First();

        if (deger.MemberFrom == myID)
            lstLastMessages.Items.Add(String.Format("From Me - To ID:{0}  -  Message: {1}", deger.MemberTo, deger.Text));
        else
            lstLastMessages.Items.Add(String.Format("From ID: {0} - To: Me -Message: {1}", deger.MemberFrom, deger.Text));
    }
```

[image]

You can see the last message between the user and his/her friends who have different `ID`. Is it possible to re-write it with one query? Or a shorter way?

Looking for some advice.

edit:
[image]

As you see my table, I have some record among users. For example, my ID is 1 and I want to find the last messages that I talked users before.

```
memberfrom 1 (its me)  memberfromTo : 2 . message: xxx 
memberfrom 2 (its me)  memberfromTo : 1 . message: yyy
memberfrom 1 (its me)  memberfromTo : 2 . message: zzzz
```

If you look above, I want to get the last message is `zzzz`. But I want to do it for each users who sent the last message.

Comment: What is a point of doing Except between *from* and *to* ids?

Comment: You selected `.Select(s => s.MemberFrom)` and `.Select(s => s.MemberTo)` which seem to be userID not messageIDs ?

Comment: I edited my question now, I hope its clear.. I am looking for a message that has sent by user.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, I wanted to get user IDs that have sent message to me by this ID.

Comment: @ai.farfa, Yes I select both, because I dont know who sent the last. Then I get whole message and comparing which one  is the last

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just group messages by `MemberTo` and `MemberFrom` fields, and get last message from each group ordered by `CreationTime`:

```
var query = from m in db.MemberMessages
            where m.MemberTo == id || m.MemberFrom == id
            group m by new { m.MemberTo, m.MemberFrom } into g
            select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationTime).First();
```

This will return both last message from user and to user you are looking for (because groups will have different keys).

UPDATE

```
var query = from m in db.MemberMessages
            let msgTo = m.MemberTo == id
            let msgFrom = m.MemberFrom == id 
            where msgTo || msgFrom
            group m by msgTo ? m.MemberFrom : m.MemberTo into g
            select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationTime).First();
```

Comment: thank you for your code but its not exactly what i want.. could you look this photo http://i.imgur.com/mW00Z5R.png

Comment: So, you want only last message in chat? Not last messages from both participants?

Comment: Yest exactly, I edited the question, you can see whatsapp picture

Comment: wow you are great :) I think tht you are master of linq. Really great code !! I appreciated you :)) that works :) thank you so much

Comment: I cant imagine how its short code.. and mine was so long and some kind of loops ... thanks again :)

Comment: @ertan2002 no problem, I like LINQ exercises :)

Answer (score 1):

if You want time related conversation just add

Timestamp field then You can uses `OrderByDescending(s => s.Timestamp).First()`

To map conversation between sender Form/To You could add **ConversationID** field before save message may be more effective than using Linq set operation for every time.

Comment: I think you are write about using conversationID, it looks better.. I will think about it. I didnt want to use time stamp.. but its not problem. I just want to find last messages of each users but also If I sent the last message, my algorithm must find it not user's .. think about whatsapp